# An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.10.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hi i got this error while bundle install...

```
Installing therubyracer (0.10.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/rajendran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/rajendran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined method `include_path' for Libv8:Module (NoMethodError)


Gem files will remain installed in /home/rajendran/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/therubyracer-0.10.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/rajendran/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/therubyracer-0.10.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.10.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

how can i resolve this..?
Note: OS - Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can try like the following:

```
$ gem uninstall libv8
$ gem install therubyracer
```

It makes working mine when i got the error.

`P.S` you need to mention your OS

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: You can comment 'trerubyracer' string in Gemfile and make bundle install.

Comment: Works for me on macOS Mojave 10.14.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @Sri, but a bit different, so paste it in not to forget it:
os - xubuntu 12.10

1. gem install therubyracer
2. gem uninstall libv8
3. gem uninstall therubyracer
4. gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.9'
   version of this gem was crucial...

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install g++ did the job ...

hope it'll helps someone

Comment: for CentOS users: `yum install gcc-c++`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

another solution without reinstallation. (in case other Rails applications use a different version) :

1.list the installed gem versions:

```
$ gem list -l therubyracer    

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
therubyracer (0.12.0)
```

2.modify your Gemfile to use one of the installed gems:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'therubyracer', '0.12.0', platforms: :ruby
```

done. now try 'bundle install' will give you a success notice.

Answer (score 0):

bundle install --path vendor/bundle
it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).